# Android. How can I slide NavigationDrawer from Espresso test library?

Tags: android, unit-testing, navigation-drawer, android-espresso

I create unit-test from Espresso in Android. My project has NavigationDrawer. I create test which must slide NavigationDrawer and click on button. In understand, how create slide action in my test.

My current solution:

```
try
    {
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But I think it's bad code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a description how to do this in android-test-kit group, explained by ValeraZakharov - [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/android-test-kit-discuss/bmLQUlcI5U4).

Comment: Thanks, but code isAssignableFrom(DrawerLayout.class); doesn't exists. Method isAssignableFrom is wrong.

Comment: For me everything works perfectly. Just import this: import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.isAssignableFrom;

Comment: It should be noted here that the Drawer functionality has been added to espresso-contrib by ValeraZakharov as mentioned by ScootrNova.

Answer (score 8):

[Espresso 1.1](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/ReleaseNotes#Version_1.1_(Released_on:_2014.1.8)) has now been out for a little while, but I've still been completely unable to find any [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) functionality within it... That is, until I found out that this functionality is actually included within a totally separate library file: `espresso-contrib`, which is available via gradle with

`androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'`

This is super briefly mentioned on [the "Why Espresso" page of the Espresso website](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso):

> If you need any functionality from the contrib library, such as [DrawerActions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions.html), copy the espresso-contrib jar from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/#git%2Fbin%2Fespresso-contrib-dependencies).

[Here's the DrawerActions documentation](https://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/docs/javadocs/apidocs/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions.html). And [here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/notes/notes/AppNavigationTest.java) is some sample code that uses it. Hopefully that puts you in the right direction; the [EspressoSamples](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples) page has no example code for this...

Comment: A working example is provided here: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp_test/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/DrawerActionsTest.java

Comment: @Rolf The link you posted is dead. Was this hosted anywhere else?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator Mh, I don't exactly remember what that was at the time, but I believe that it could have been this: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/blob/master/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/android/testing/notes/notes/AppNavigationTest.java

Answer (score 3):

openDrawer() was deprecated, you can use this code instead. 
I can confirm it works

```
onView(withId(R.id.my_drawer_layout)).perform(DrawerActions.open());
```

Comment: Hi,in my code cannot resolve method open() error is showing.Can u please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

NavigationDrawer support is coming soon in the next release of Espresso. For the time being, you can implement your own ViewAction, where you would add the code inside your Runnable. This is an incomplete solution because you will likely experience timing issues related to opening/closing of the drawer. Espresso 1.1 will take care of this.

Comment: Espresso is young library. Examples are too few. I will move to UIAutomator. Your answer in google groups helped me.

Comment: Have you seen https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSamples? If you think something is missing, you're welcome to request and even add more samples.